# R ggplot geom_point - How to order by values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I searched very intensively, but could not find a solution to my problem.

I want to get the data in my graph ordered by values so that *Tussilago farfara* comes first and *Euphorbia cyparissias* comes last.

This is my dataset:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
ggplot(data = artSlope, aes(x = slope, y = art)) +
    geom_point() + 
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            panel.background = element_blank(), 
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + 
    labs(y = "species", title = "phenological shifts") +  
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0) + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = slope + se, xmin = slope - se))
```

And this is the result I get:
[image]

How do I get the graph ordered by slope (x axis)?

Comment: check out http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7433_4537ea5073dc4162950abb715f513469.html

Comment: `aes(slope, forcats::fct_reorder(art, -slope))`.

Comment: Good question.  A helpful addition would be to include the data set, not by a graphic, but by using `dput(artSlope)` and pasting the result into the question.  This will allow others to easily [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) the example.  That said, @Axeman 's comment above should produce the graphic you are looking for.